# How to find normalisation constant for a pdf in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a pdf with sample space from [-v,v] where 0 <= v < 1
and the pdf is, with c as normalization constant

```
f(v) = c*v^2 for v in [-v,v]
f(v) = 0 otherwise
```

Now is there a way to tell matlab to find my c for a given v?
I know I could integrate it and it should equal one and then find c, but this seems like it should be available somewhere [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/makedist.html), but I can't find it

Comment: A Provability Density Function, right?

Comment: The integral of `v^2` is `v^3 / 3`.  You can use that to solve for `c`.

Comment: I know the solution for my simple example. I was just wondering if there is such a thing for more complex pdfs where the solution is not immediately obvious. Atleast I thought this would be a task that is often done(finding a normalization constant for a pdf) and thus there exists a toolbox for it. PS: A negative answers is also an answer. It's just that sometimes these functionalities are not well know or documented but they exist, that's why I ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that such a function exists, but I could be wrong. However, you can use a numeric integration function in Matlab like:

```
I = integrate(function, xmin, xmax);
c = 1/I; % your normalization constant
```

This way you can always integrate your pdf, even more complex ones.